# Count correct answer on online exam in jsp

Tags: jsp

I am working in a project where online exam is a part, i'm doing this for my sem. exam.
I cam creating a online exam system(a part of project) where I am able to fetch  questio with answer from DB but i am not able to count the correct answer.I need help on that.
Any help will much appreciate as I need to do it ASAP.

Coding is done using jsp scriplet
code to fetch data:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<html>
  <form method="post" action="res2.jsp">
    <table>
      <%
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cms","root", "root");
Statement st=connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select * from quiz");
int i=1;
while(rs.next()){
%>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <%=i%>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%=rs.getString("quest")%>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" value="QA" name="radio<%=i%>"/><%=rs.getString("QA")%>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" value="QB" name="radio<%=i%>"/><%=rs.getString("QB")%>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" value="QC" name="radio<%=i%>"/><%=rs.getString("QC")%>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" value="QD" name="radio<%=i%>"/><%=rs.getString("QD")%>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value='<%=rs.getString("correctAns")%>' name="ans<%=i%>"/>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <%
i++;
}
%>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="submit" value="submit"></input>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</html>
```

Now code to see the correct answer.Here I got stuck...

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%
    String id[]= new String[6];
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
      id[i]=request.getParameter("radio"+i);
      System.out.println(id[i]);
    }
    String str[]= new String[6];
    for(int j=0;j<6;j++){
      str[j]=request.getParameter("ans"+j);
      System.out.println(str[j]);
    }

    int count=0;
    //String answers[]=str.split(" ");
    for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
      if(id.equals(str)){

      count++;
      //System.out.println(id[i]);
      }
    }
    out.println("Your "+count+" answers are correct");
%>
```

I am able to see the data which are selecting in the jsp page and also see the correct ans,but while counting the correct answer I am getting 0 value.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean:

```
if(id[i].equals(str[i])){

count++;
//System.out.println(id[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this works.

```
if((str[i]!=null)&&(id[i]!=null)){
    if(id[i].equals(str[i])){
        count++;
    }
}
```